# Fixing a messed up Music Library

Tags: rhythmbox, music, file-properties

I was editing the information in my library in rhythmbox, and everything got royally messed up somehow. Many song titles, artists, and albums are completely wrong. I'm wondering if there's an way I can fix the properties automatically, like windows media player allows with it's album database comparison thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MusicBrainz Picard](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/picard/) to rewrite tags of your music library.

It should help you to reconstruct the messed up tags by downloading them from the [MusicBrainz library](http://musicbrainz.org/).

If you have the title on the file name, you can start by generating tags from file names (Tools -> Generate tags from file name). Then, with this as a starting point, you can use Picard to look up on the MusicBrainz library the other tags.

Or, if you not even have the correct file name you can use the [acoustic fingerprint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_fingerprint) function, enabling it from the options (see [here](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/AcoustID)). In practice it analyzes the song and automatically (should) recognize which song it is.